# Drop of water in zero gravity

Tags: vacuum, surface-tension, wetting

Suppose there is a drop of water in gravity-free space. A man slowly touches the drop and keeps his fingers touched. What happens? Does the drop change its shape? Or wet his fingers? Or there is no change?

What if I take mercury?

Note: Consider no oil initially dry fingers.

Comment: I'd guess that the drop will wet the finger due to surface tension once its shape is broken. If the touch is slow enough, then it might just be that the drop stays spherical.

Comment: It depends on the wettability of human skin w.r.t. water and mercury.

Comment: in the general case, i believe that the water will wet his finger, but the mercury would stay together(cohesion and adhesion forces obviously)

Comment: You can watch [NASA: Amazing Experiments with Water in Zero Gravity](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntQ7qGilqZE) in YouTube.

Comment: The drop will try to keep its surface energy as less as possible, so if the human finger touches a point, at that point the drop will spread to make an acute angle of contact with the surface of the finger and will form a bowl shaped structure. It won't spread further since the surface area would increase which will require greater amount of energy than it was present as a spherical ball.

Comment: Also the spread will due to greater interaction of water with the surface of finger than with air thus, lowering the energy.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? Are you asking if the man will get his finger wet? Or how the shape of the drop will change, or something else. At the moment your question *what happens next* is rather vague,

Comment: @Sikander Not necessarily true. Like I say, it depends on the wettability of the human finger. If the finger-liquid interfacial free energy is small enough relative to the liquid-air surface tension then the drop will completely spread.

Comment: @JohnRennie I am asking that does the drop retains it shape or according to Martin and Lelouch it would wet the fingers?

Comment: How oily are the fingers?

Comment: Consider no oil initially dry fingers.

Comment: Related: [Wet Washcloth in Space](http://youtu.be/l0D20Pp0WAc?t=55s).

Comment: Got my answer @Qmechanic.